# Fitting with only few data points

Tags: fitting, data

I am trying to fit an upside down Cauchy distribution to very few data points which are seen in the picture below:

[image]

I know that the minimum should be near `x = 4`, and I tried `NonLinearModelFit`, but the result was very bad.

Is there a way to get better fit results with few data points?

Comment: Please show the code you've tried.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One can't expect much with estimating 5 coefficients (a, b, c, d, and error variance) with just 7 points.  That also makes it difficult for getting convergence to the maximum likelihood or least-squares estimates as good starting values become more critical.  (The default starting values are all 1.0 and most of the final estimates are far away from 1.0.)

And finally, one's brain (at least mine) doesn't necessarily think in terms of least squares: a curve that one might superimpose upon the data in one's head is not necessarily what a least squares solution looks like.

Here is a fit with mean and single prediction bands:

```
data = {{1, 2637}, {2, 2722}, {3, 2608}, {4, 2471}, {5, 2685}, {6, 2630}, {7, 2784}};
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, a - b/(d \[Pi] (1 + (-c + x)^2/d^2)),
  {{a, 2800}, {b, 1900}, {c, 4}, {d, 0.1}}, x, MaxIterations -> 10000];
nlm["BestFitParameters"]
(* {a -> 2700.41, b -> 670336., c -> 3.61325, d -> 0.000160892} *)

f = Join[{nlm[x]}, nlm["MeanPredictionBands"], nlm["SinglePredictionBands"]];
g = Plot[f, {x, 0, 8},
  PlotStyle -> {{Black, Solid}, {Green, Dotted}, {Green, Dotted}, {Red, Dotted}, {Red, Dotted}}];
Show[ListPlot[data, PlotRange -> {{0, 8}, {2300, 3000}}], g]
```

[image: Data and fit with prediction bands]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Is there a way to "force" Mathematica to place the minimum at x=4?

Comment: Certainly.  You just set `c` to be 4.  But you lose all ability to estimate how good that estimate might be.

Comment: Just one last thing. If I remove the "MeanPredictionBands" and the "SinglePredictionBands" Mathematica doesn't plot the black line entirely on the given range. How can I force it to do so?

Comment: Add in `PlotRange -> {All, {2300, 3000}}` to the `Plot` command.